# How to use ExecutorSubscribableChannel

Tags: java, spring, stomp, spring-messaging

Related with the question [autowire simpmessagingtemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925951/could-not-autowire-no-beans-of-simpmessagingtemplate-type-found)

I am having problem the class ExecutorSubscribableChannel. I want the server to send a asynchronous message to the browser. **How can I use properly ExecutorSubscribableChannel** ?

Example:

```
public class GreetingController {


    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    public void setTemplate(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(5000); // simulated delay
        this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", "Hello World");
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }
}
```

but the "hello world" text that I am sending in the line

```
this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", "Hello World");
```

is not being received by the browser. Everything else works fine.

The beans configuration is:

```
<bean id="executorSC" class="org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel"/>

<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="executorSC"/>
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was written due a bug in Intellij IDEA. The response is in [Could not autowire. No beans of SimpMessagingTemplate type found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925951/could-not-autowire-no-beans-of-simpmessagingtemplate-type-found)

A [ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123964) has been create in JetBrains to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try using this configuration

```
<websocket:message-broker
    application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/ws">
        <websocket:sockjs />
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic/greetings" />
</websocket:message-broker>
```

insted of

```
<bean id="executorSC" class="org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel"/>
```